# XML to HTML using c# without using xslt

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have been searching all over the web, i'm assuming some one has to have needed this before me and done it better, for an xml to HTML. I have a very standard xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<W-TIBCPTRs>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO VALIDE="NON">5b1</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
  </W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO>511</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0068078</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
  </W-TIBCPTR>
</W-TIBCPTRs>
```

And I would like to parse this to something like

```
TYPTRT CLAFCNO NUMCLI   TYPACT
FDR2 R  5b1    0067781    D
FDR2 R  511    0068078    D
```

and if i have an Attribut like

```
<CLAFCNO VALIDE="NON">5b1</CLAFCNO>
```

i need to have a background color in html file

Comment: If you dont want to use xslt, then you will need to iterate through your xml using the XmlDocument or XDocument classes.

Comment: Ok have you some example how can use it with XmlDocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a console app that demonstrates how to iterate through your document. It uses an XPath statement to locate all the "W-TIBCPTR" nodes, then iterated through the children of those nodes.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine("<table>");
        sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>TYPTRT</td><td>CLAFCNO</td><td>NUMCLI</td><td>TYPACT</td></tr>");

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("XMLFile2.xml");

        XmlNodeList rowElements = doc.SelectNodes("W-TIBCPTRs/W-TIBCPTR");

        foreach(XmlElement rowElement in rowElements)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<tr>");

            foreach (XmlElement valueElement in rowElement.ChildNodes)
            {

                if (valueElement.GetAttribute("VALIDE") == "NON")
                    sb.AppendFormat("<td bgcolor='Red'>{0}</td>", valueElement.InnerText);
                else
                    sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", valueElement.InnerText);
            }

            sb.AppendLine("</tr>");


        }

        sb.AppendLine("</table>");

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    } 
}
```